# Create CSS3 for background image

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if there is an easy way to recreate the attached image using CSS3.

I've included this image as a page background but one of the senior devs told me there is an easy way to create this image background using CSS3.

I thought the background images can be done using CSS3 for repeatable patterns. But this image doesn't have any patterns that I could see.

Is that possible for this image?[image: Background Image]

Comment: No, there's no way you can do this with CSS3 easily (I can't even think of a way to do it all). Maybe the senior developer was thinking of SVG or HTML5 Canvas?

Comment: Or maybe he was refering to base64 image.

Comment: Turning this image into an SVG will save a lot on the file size, compared to jpg, gif or png. And it would look crisp at any size, including on retina screens, that would be the big advantage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is interesting as experiment, but its not pragmatic.

You can convert an image to css [here](http://www.imgtocss.com/). PNGs work best.

Warning though, you will get tons of lines of HTML + CSS to create this image. It will come out pixel perfect though. I will also warn you that I tried uploading it to Jsfiddle, Jsbin and Codepen - all of them would just hang. Pen loaded and I couldn't save it since it's larger than 1MB.

[This is what my text editor looks like with your image converted to CSS though.](http://screencast.com/t/FW0PIBlHL)

This is just for reference. Yes, you can convert to CSS, but it doesn't mean that you should. I suppose it might be useful for things like email? But not for large images.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I was able to convince the sr developer to use an SVG.